# Hencky nets/slip-line fields on the the interior of a closed domain

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

This is a [crossed post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/658049/slip-line-fields-on-the-the-interior-of-a-closed-domain).

The equations for Hencky nets are usually solved in the *exterior* of some domain; typical examples are the upper half plane or the exterior of a circle. I would like to know about examples of these nets but in the interior of a domain (most importantly, a unit disk).